# Переклад з російської «осколочное ранение»

Tags: переклад, from-russian

На Вікіпедії час від часу зустрічаю статті про бійців, де можна побачити переклад з російської терміну `осколочное ранение`, [наприклад](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87):

> отримав осколкове поранення біля Слов'янська

Google [пропонує](https://translate.google.com/#ru/uk/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) переклад саме такий переклад. Натомість `осколок` [перекладається](https://translate.google.com/#ru/uk/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA) як `уламок`.

Як правильно перекласти російськомовний термін?

Comment: Цікаво що Ліна Костенко використала саме осколок: "Застряло серце, мов осколок в грудях, Нічого, все це вилікує смерть" (Л.Костенко)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можливо `скалкове поранення`, бо найдавніший приклад вживання знайдений мною подає саме такий варіант. СУМ на [скалка](http://sum.in.ua/s/skalka) містить уривок з Лесі Українки написаний 1896 року:

> Часами тільки бомба огнева
>   Могильну тишу розбивала гучно
>   І всіх навколо ранила скалками.

Гугл на `"скалкове поранення"` (саме в лапках) видає трохи більше 30 [результатів](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%22&*).

Також значення описане у вікіпедійній статті [Скалка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) говорить, що можна таки використати скалку:

> **Скалка** — відколотий, відбитий шматок чогось твердого; осколок, тонка
>   тріска, переважно сухого дерева, гострий відламок металу, скла тощо,
>   які застряли у шкірі, тілі. Тонкий загострений довгастий кристал
>   льоду, інею тощо. Краплі жиру на поверхні рідини

Хоча з народного сучасного словника на [r2u](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) маємо підтримку саме осколкового:

> **Осколочный** – скалковий, скалчастий, осколковий, уламковий, друзковий:
>   • *осколочное ранение – осколкове поранення*.

Стаття [Скабка](http://sum.in.ua/s/skabka) на СУМ, але як вказано в коментарях скабка більше підходить для "занози":

> **СКА́БКА**, и, *жін*. Тонка, гостра трісочка, гострий осколок металу, скла
>   та ін., які застряли у шкірі, в тілі; скалка. — *А що, чи скабку виняла*
>   [вийняла] *з ноги?* (Ганна Барвінок, Опов.., 1902, 77); *Не помічають*
>   [теслярі] *ні скабок, ні вдертої шкіри на мозолястих руках* (Олександр
>   Довженко, Зачарована Десна, 1957, 554).

Comment: Скабка то швидше "заноза".

Comment: Народний — як я розумію, не авторитетний (тобто може містити корисну інформацію, але не може бути істиною у останній інстанції). Також підтримую Artemix, що «скабка» — то зовсім не те, то дуже маленька трісочка (рос. «заноза»). Але «скалковий» — так, ІМХО, хороша ідея.

Comment: Будь ласка, почніть з того, чому не годиться *осколок*, бо в читача може скластися враження, що вам просто не подобається, як звучить це сполучення літер, тому "пропонуєте…"

Comment: @NashBridges, я так розумію, Yola вважає прийнятними обидва варіанти: «осколкове» і «скалкове». Але перевагу надає «скалковому». Yola, я правильно Вас зрозумів, чи ні?

Answer (score 10):

Одне із значень слова "[осколок](http://sum.in.ua/s/oskolok)" в СУМ:

> ОСКО́ЛОК, лка, чол.   Дрібна частинка бомби, снаряда, міни і т. ін.,
>   що відколюються під час вибуху. Гриміла артилерійська канонада,
>   сипались зенітні осколки з цеба.., а Самійло Вихор того не чув (Василь
>   Кучер, Чорноморці, 1956, 360); Тимко побачив нашого бійця, що біг без
>   шапки і шинелі, він правою рукою підтримував відбиту осколком щелепу
>   (Григорій Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 501).

Стаття "[осколковий](http://sum.in.ua/s/oskolkovyj)" наводить конкретне словосполучення "осколкова рана":

> ОСКО́ЛКОВИЙ, а, е, Утворений осколком, завданий осколком. Осколкова
>   рана.